# Exception when use wss4j to insert a X509 certificate

Tags: java, soap, x509certificate, wss4j

An exception exists when I use the wss4j to sign a X509 in the soap header.
My code is here:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    Document document = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getOwnerDocument(); 



    Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance();   

    WSSecSignature signature = new WSSecSignature();


    WSSecHeader secuHeader = new WSSecHeader("",false);
    secuHeader.insertSecurityHeader(document);

    String user = "16c73ab6-b892-458f-abf5-2f875f74882e";
    String password ="security";

    signature.setUserInfo(user, password);
    signature.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.X509_KEY_IDENTIFIER);
    signature.build(document, crypto, secuHeader);
```

I just use the default crypto.properties in wss4j. However, an exception exists:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: UNIMPLEMENTED
    at weblogic.xml.domimpl.ElementBase.setIdAttributeNS(ElementBase.java:327)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMUtils.setAttributeID(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyInfo.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyInfo.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:554)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:479)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:385)
```

I wanna to know how to solve this exception. Thanks for your help!

Comment: could it be it doesn't implement dom level 3?

Comment: Hi,@tom I also go to oracle forum, dom level 3 could be the reason,but I want to know how to implement it here? Thank you very much.

Comment: if you don't have a dom3 parser in the tool you're using, you have to serialise the document as XML, reparse it with a level 3 parser (all the modern ones) and sign it with that.